# Customizing the 'Authorizing...' message (top left corner) of a Blazor Wasm app

Tags: blazor, webassembly

When a Blazor WebAssembly application loads, it first downloads blazor.webassembly.js and all the .NET assemblies of the application. Until everything is loaded, it displays a loading message. We can easily change this message in the `wwwroot/index.html`

```
<body>
<!--  Here -->
<app>Loading...</app>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

But also, if we secure ou application with authentication (`CascadingAuthenticationState`, `AuthorizeRouteView`, ...), we also see 'Authorizing...' in the top left corner.

My question is: how this message can be customized ? I didn't see anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App.razor` you can:

```
...
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <Authorizing>
        Some other authorizing message...
    </Authorizing>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <RedirectToLogin />
        }
        else
        {
            <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
...
```

Comment: May I ask you where I can find any documentation on this ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authorizerouteview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#properties